# Viewinjection with unity failing

Tags: c#, navigation, prism, unity-container, prism-4

I have trouble getting navigation working using Prism 4.

I've set up a test solution in which I have a shell with a region called `MainRegion`:

```
<Window x:Class="PrismNavigationTest.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        Title="ShellView" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Next I have a bootstrapper that adds a `Module` that is located in a different project to my `modulecatalog`:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    Type module = typeof(Module.ModuleInit);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo("Module", module.AssemblyQualifiedName));

    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
}
```

In the Initialize method on the `ModuleInit` class I'm trying to change the view of the `mainregion`.

```
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    private IRegionManager regionManager;

    public ModuleInit(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO This works
        //regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", () => container.Resolve<View>());

        // TODO This doesn't work
        container.RegisterType<object, View>("View1");
        regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].RequestNavigate(new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Using view discovery works but not view injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `Bootstrapper`.

In the `InitializeShell` method I resolved a Shell from the container using this code:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
```

I changed this to instead use the already initialized shell:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
```

Im still a bit confused by this but I think it has to do with unity creating new object and not singletons per default when resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line;

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "View1");
```

to this;

```
var view1 = new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", view1);
```

Also, it seems there is another problem, you are calling `() => container.Resolve<View>()` when displaying the view with `RegisterViewWithRegion`. Then it seems you have already registered the view. But in the "not working" part, you are registering the `View` again.

Comment: I changed the "View1" to a Uri instead but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. Regarding the registration of the view, Unity is able to resolve my view even if I havn't registered it before.

Comment: can you check whether your bootstrapper class derives from UnityBootstrapper and you are employing the same container in ModuleInit class?

Comment: can you also try RequestNavigate method of the region itself; regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].RequestNavigate(new Uri("View1", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: The bootstrapper class is derived from UnityBootstrapper and I inject the container in the constructor. Edited my original post to show the entire ModuleInit class. I also tried calling RequestNavigate on the region itself but it didn't change anything.

Comment: can you change registration name ("View1") to any other name? maybe another object is registrated with View1 name...

Comment: I changed the name but still the same. Also if I put a breakpoint in the view's constructor I can see that the view is created ok.

Comment: then try restarting Visual Studio:)